How to capture the “time=” parameter from ffmpeg output?
I am using EndeavourOS and if I play audio with the command ffmpeg -i test.flac -f alsa default, the terminal shows this sort of output:
size=N/A time=00:00:21.31 bitrate=N/A speed=1.22x 

I would like to grab the 'time=' parameter and its value there. I know ffmpeg outputs to STDERR, so, I know to redirect 2>1, so I try:
ffmpeg -i test.flac -f alsa default 2>&1 | grep time

…and the terminal stays completely blank at this point (though the music plays just fine).
I've also tried:
ffmpeg -i test.flac -f alsa default 2>test.txt

…and in a second terminal session:
tail -f test.txt | grep time

…and still blank, though if I just tail the file without the grep part, I see the relevant line of text with an ever-incrementing time= value.
I know that it will be suggested to use ffplay, but I'm dealing with a lot of code using ffmpeg and switching is not an option. I'm really more interested in knowing an answer to why grep just doesn't seem to work on ffmpeg STDERR output, no matter where it's redirected to! Almost secondarily: is there a way to extract the 'current position in stream' time value using only ffmpeg?

In light of comments below:
ffmpeg -v
ffmpeg version n7.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 14.2.1 (GCC) 20240910

And the truncated output from just playing the music, no redirects:
TAGDATE         : 1623718801
encoder         : Lavf61.7.100
Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s
Metadata:
encoder         : Lavc61.19.100 pcm_s16le
size=N/A time=00:00:15.36 bitrate=N/A speed=1.34x  

And some examples of what I can and can't grep from that output:
[zelenka Desktop]$ ffmpeg -i test.flac -f alsa default 2>&1 | grep Duration
Duration: 00:21:10.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 690 kb/s
^C^C^C
[zelenka Desktop]$ ffmpeg -i test.flac -f alsa default 2>&1 | grep Audio
Stream #0:0: Audio: flac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16    
Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s
^C^C^C
[zelenka Desktop]$ ffmpeg -i test.flac -f alsa default 2>&1 | grep time=
^C^C^C

(And at this point I have to Ctrl+C to interrupt, as nothing appears on-screen). Grepping the 'static' data works; grepping the dynamic part of the size=N/A time=00:00:15.36 bitrate=N/A speed=1.34x line output doesn't.

Edited to provide working answer:
In session 1, I can now issue this command:
ffmpeg -stats_period 1 -i test.flac -f alsa default |& awk -v RS="\r" -v FS='[= ]' 'NR > 1 && /time/ {print $4; fflush("/dev/stdout")}' | tee test.txt

Which says for ffmpeg to output a progress count every 1 second. The progress output is then passed through to awk, searching for the 'out_time=' line of progress. That's then flushed and written to a test.txt file.
In a second terminal, I then issue this command:
tail -f test.txt | cut -c-8

...which produces output like this:
[zelenka Desktop]$ tail -1 test.txt | grep --line-buffered ":" |cut -c-8
00:00:04
00:00:05
00:00:06
00:00:07
00:00:08
00:00:09

...which I can use!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239350/how-to-extract-duration-time-from-ffmpeg-output  I belive you want the answer by Louis Marascio since you want to use ffmpeg and not ffplay or ffprobe...

But that isn't working for me. If I pipe the ffmpeg through grep, I get nothing. And you'll note that Louis' main contribution to the answer you cite was to point out the need to redirect STDERR to STDOUT ...which I'm already doing. So no, I don't believe that answer helps. I'll certainly agree that if I grep for 'Duration', I get some output, but not if I grep for "time".

ffmpeg -i test.flac -f alsa default |& awk -v RS="\r" 'NR > 1 && /time/'

If you only want to see the time field:
$ ffmpeg -i test.flac -f alsa default |& awk -v RS="\r" 'NR > 1 && /time/ {print $2}'
time=00:00:04.36
time=00:00:04.92
time=00:00:05.47
time=00:00:06.03
time=00:00:06.59
time=00:00:07.15
time=00:00:07.70

If you don't want to see time= part:
$ ffmpeg -i test.flac -f alsa default |& awk -v RS="\r" -v FS='[= ]' 'NR > 1 && /time/ {print $4}'
00:00:04.36
00:00:04.92
00:00:05.47
00:00:06.03
00:00:06.59
00:00:07.15
00:00:07.70

If you still want to redirect output to another file you can follow
flush the output in awk but remember that the more things you do in
the pipeline the slower it becomes:
$ ffmpeg -i test.flac -f alsa default |& awk -v RS="\r" -v FS='[= ]' 'NR > 1 && /time/ {print $4; fflush("/dev/stdout")}' | tee /tmp/HERE

ffmpeg -i test.flac -f alsa default 2>&1 | grep time doesn't work
because grep is line-oriented but a newline for it means \n (ASCII
0xa, you can see it man ascii) but ffmpeg uses \r (ASCII 0xd) to
go the beginning of line and clear it so that time info is always
shown in the same line. You can see it with strace:
$ strace -f -s 4096 ffmpeg -i test.flac -f alsa default |& grep time=
[pid  2666] write(2, "size=N/A time=00:00:05.47 bitrate=N/A speed=3.24x    \r", 54 <unfinished ...>


What does the RS= bit mean

It's awk record separator, you can more about it GNU awk
manual.

If I have understood the question correctly, this is the desired output: 00:00:21.31

@Cyrus: I updated my answer

So, first off 'wow'. But second: what's happening? What does the RS= bit mean, and (frankly) what does all the other stuff mean? Why is this working (which it is) and a simple grep isn't? All that said: thank you. That is a huge deal for me. Thanks.
I can't mark the answer because I don't have the points: but this is correct and something I can definitely work with.

Sorry for the follow-up, but how does one get that time extract into a variable that's readable by another session? I thought I'd simply redirect to a text file, so do
 ffmpeg -i test.flac -f alsa default |& awk -v RS="\r" 'NR > 1 && /time/' > test.txt

And then tail test.txt in a second session. But the tail session simply hangs after a few lines of output. It doesn't seem a reliable way to extract current play position, in other words.

Have you used tail -f to continuously read the file? https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html

@user512278: I updated my answer to address your questions. You really cannot accept an answer to your own question? They should stop "fixing" the site.

Thank you for the update, which contains the essential answer: grep works on line delimited by \n, but ffmpeg delineates lines with \r. That explains why grep won't work ordinarily, for me at least. I expect that this issue is the reason why the output from your commands is still not trivially usable in tailing a file output, for example. I shall have to experiment with translating \r into \n or something. Still: that's more than 90% of my question answered, so many thanks.

I expect that this issue is the reason why the output from your commands is still not trivially usable in tailing a file output, for example. , no this is due to buffering, I also explained how to solve it

You did. I missed it. I've now incorporated that into my original post. Your answer is complete and usable: thank you. I simply have never even heard of fflush before, let alone needed to use it: in this respect, working with ffmpeg is very much sui generis though I guess it's to be expected! The fact it uses carriage returns rather than line feeds: obvious when you look at its output, but not something that I've ever routinely had to worry about before. Live and learn, I guess: and you certainly taught well. I think I've mastered marking answers, too, so that will happen shortly!

The fact it uses carriage returns rather than line feeds: obvious when you look at its output, but not something that I've ever routinely had to worry about before. it uses carriage returns only when it wants to replace the current line, you can try it yourself to see how it works: while true; do printf '\rabc'; sleep 1; printf '\rdef'; sleep 1; done

Yes, that's what I meant. It outputs a pile of what I previously called 'static' data, which is trivially greppable, because each line appears on a new line. But the 'dynamic' stuff is over-written each time, so that it all happens on one continuously-updated line. It's obvious that, at that point, it has switched to using carriage returns without the line feed. However, unless you're primed to think of that difference, it's easy to miss (which I did). Once you spot what it's doing to display its output, however, it's clear why 'Duration' is greppable, and 'time' isn't (without tricks!)

ffmpeg has an option -progress to write output progress to a file (or any URL or pipe).
So run ffmpeg -i test.flac -progress myfile.txt -f alsa default
and then grep "time=" myfile.txt | tail -1

This is pretty useful! It doesn't explain why grep won't trivially work on ffmpeg output, but as that's been answered above by another poster, I suppose it doesn't have to! :-) This is, however, a brilliantly usable way of extracting the current play position without having to write something that looks like hieroglyphics, so thank you.

Unfortunately, I'm still struggling. I can certainly do tail -f test.txt | grep "time=" and get usable output (of 'out_time=00:00:26.852838' and so on, continuously). But the minute I try and pipe that through awk to extract just the time component, without the text label, I get nothing at all. The command tail -f test.txt | grep "time=" | awk -F'=' '{print $2}' produces no output at all, for example. I don't get why this is so hard! I do text stripping with sed and awk all the time, but anything to do with ffmpeg output fails miserably!

it has nothing to do with ffmpeg, it's also due to buffering: tail -f test.txt | grep --line-buffered "time=" | awk -F'=' '{print $2}'

Indeed. I've never had to deal with buffering before, but ffmpeg is very much a 'real time' process where it becomes an issue. Appreciate the insights.
